# Data cleaning: regex to replace numbers

Tags: pandas

I have this dataframe:

```
p=pd.DataFrame({'text':[2,'string']})
```

and trying to replace digit 2 by an 'a' using this code:

```
p['text']=p['text'].str.replace('\d+', 'a')
```

But instead of letter `a` and get `NaN`?

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your dataframe, the first value of the `text` column is actually a **number**, not a string, thus the NaN error when you try to call **`.str`**. Just convert it to a string first:

```
p['text'] = p['text'].astype(str).str.replace('\d+', 'a')
```

Output:

```
>>> p
     text
0       a
1  string
```

(Note that `.str.replace` is soon going to change the default value of `regex` from True to False, so you won't be able to use regular expressions without passing `regex=True`, e.g. `.str.replace('\d+', 'a', regex=True)`)